# Prove that $K=\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb{R}^3\ :\ x^2+yz=x+1\}$ is not compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $K=\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb{R}^3\ :\ x^2+yz=x+1\}$

Show that $K$ is not compact

Comment: It is sufficient to show it is not bounded. Can you find $(0,y,z)\in K$ with arbitrarily large $y$?

Comment: why $(0,y,z)$ ?. I dont understand

Comment: I think the OP was trying to make life simpler - if $K$ is unbounded, then one of its projections should be, too. He noticed that the projection onto the $y,z$-plane is unbounded, which incidentally makes life easier since when $x=0$ you don't have to deal with quadratics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K$ is "clearly" closed, as the solution set of a continuous function. So the only way it can fail to be compact is to be unbounded.

Now check that $(0, n , \frac{1}{n}) \in K$ for all $n$ and its norm is $>n$.